# jquery validate - valid if hidden field has a value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate a field based on the value of a hidden field. I tried this custom rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cityselected", function() {
    if ($('#featureID').val() == "") return false;
    else return true;
});

cityselect: {
    required: true,
    cityselected: true
},
```

featureID is a hidden input which I need to check has a value. This doesnt seem to work though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the class "required" to the hidden input.

Answer (score 2):

If your plugin version is greater than 1.9, you'll have to explicitly add hidden to the validation process, like that when you initialize the plugin :

```
$("#form").validate({
  // Do not ignore hidden fields
  ignore: []
});
```

Comment: You are correct... this is the way to do it with the later versions of the plugin.  However, in all fairness to the OP, this was not an option in 2011 when hidden fields were not ignored.